# A story about a family fighting alongside reptilian aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading this around the age of ten, which would be about 1984. The aliens were lizard people very similar to the ones from "V" on television. A kissing scene from the book describes their forked flicking tongues entwining. I also recall a weapon used by the humans that seemed to be...exploding foil-wrap balls? The human family was led by a father with several children who befriended and fought alongside a lizard couple against the lizard race. The cover art on the book seemed to be a convertible-type transport with no top and the lizards driving. Thanks!

---

This was a novel. I recall it being just one book.

Comment: Novel, short story, comic?

Comment: Ive got the book your describing but I cant find it...*cries* I will keep looking....found it, see below

Answer (score 6):

The book your describing sounds like the second of the Guss trilogy by Ward Hawkins (link to cover is at the bottom) its called Sword of Fire. Its the only book of the three ive ever been able to get, im always on the look out for the other two-

Guss

1. Red Flame Burning (1985)
2. Sword of Fire (1985)
3. Blaze of Wrath (1986)

The foil wrap balls in this book are explosives disguised as chewing gum wrappers which are detonated with a mental command, the lizard aliens are all telepathic and earless and can only speak to humans who have had a telepathic implant.
Hope this is the right book...and series

http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/h/ward-hawkins/sword-of-fire.htm

Answer (score 1):

"Eye of the Monster" by Andre Norton?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that does not seem to be it. Cover art on the book had a reptilian face in foreground.

Comment: Could there be different cover art on different editions?